# Singleton How to Declare NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, singleton

I am trying to implement a singleton which contains an NSMutableArray* what I've done so far is below.

Singleton.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Singleton : NSObject{
    NSMutableArray* ClassArray;
}

@property NSMutableArray* ClassArray;
+(Singleton*) getInstance;



- (void) SetClassArray:(NSMutableArray *)InputClassArray;
- (NSMutableArray*) GetClassArray;
```

Singleton.m

```
#import "Singleton.h"

@implementation Singleton

@synthesize ClassArray;

static Singleton *singletonInstance;

+ (Singleton*)getInstance{
    if (singletonInstance == nil) {
        singletonInstance = [[super alloc] init];
    }
    return singletonInstance;
}

- (void) SetClassArray:(NSMutableArray *)InputClassArray{
    ClassArray = InputClassArray;
}

- (NSMutableArray*) GetClassArray{
    return ClassArray;
}
@end
```

what I'm wondering is where does [[NSMutableArray alloc]init]; go? or do i not need it. Also when ClassArray is initialised i want some default values, (the return from another function,[DatabaseFunctions GetClassDefaultArray] ) again where does this go?. I'm assuming the line below singletonInstance = [[super alloc] init]; however it doesn't accept ClassArray.

I have an application consisting of four view controllers, what I need is an nsmutablearray that can be accessed and written to from any of these views. There are three others in total.
Thanks

Comment: FYI - please find a modern tutorial or modern code to emulate. Your posted code is very out of date. Get rid of the `ClassArray` ivar and get rid of the `@synthesize` line. Neither is needed anymore. And if you do want an ivar, don't put it in the .h file. And please use standard naming conventions. Class names begin with uppercase letters. Method and variables names should begin with lowercase letters.

Comment: Why do you call `[[super alloc] init]`? It should be `[[self alloc] init]` or simply `[[Singleton alloc] init]`. You should also look at using `dispatch_once` for singletons instead of checking to see if `singletonInstance` is `nil`.

Comment: is it possible you can send me a modern tutorial for singletons, having a google I'm not sure which is old/new proper way of doing it etc.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm wondering is where does [[NSMutableArray alloc]init]; go? or do i not need it

That depends on what you expect in your getter. Is reasonable for your use case to return `nil` in `GetClassArray`?

You could guard against it by returning an empty array if it is `nil`:

```
- (NSMutableArray*) GetClassArray{
    if ( ! ClassArray ) {
        ClassArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }

    return ClassArray;
}
```

> i want some default values

You can populate your array as you see fit whenever you want, the best place to start would probably be your init method:

```
+ (Singleton*)getInstance{
    if (singletonInstance == nil) {
        singletonInstance = [[super alloc] init];
        NSMutableArray *array = ...;
        [singletoneinstance SetClassArray:array];
    }
    return singletonInstance;
}
```

As a side note, I would recommend reading up on some [naming conventions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Conventions/Conventions.html) so you don't mixed up between class names and variable names in the future.